# Add Columns in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How to add Columns B2 till E2 and put it in total column F2. And this to continue dynamically in this case till B12 + E12 = F12?

Sub CaclulateRatio()

```
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Others #Dev/#Deals"

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=Iferror(RC[-8]/RC[-7],0)"

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Country/Area #Dev/#Deals"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=Iferror(RC[-7]/RC[-6],0)"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Geo #Dev/#Deals"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=Iferror(RC[-6]/RC[-5],0)"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Corporate #Dev/#Deals"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=Iferror(RC[-5]/RC[-4],0)"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Total # Of Deals Per Level"
    'oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(B2:E2)"
   ' oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
   ' oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
   ' oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B:I").Delete
    oEXLWB.Sheets("ExportDeviations").Columns(oEXLWB.Sheets("ExportDeviations").Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Column).Delete
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to add a screenshot of my excel sheet for the sum of rows and put them in the Total column but its telling me about some reputation stuff and rejecting me to proceed further.

Comment: can you upload the file to any file sharing site and share the link here. we will upload it for you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyy1vd6hybro5qc/Sum.png

Comment: I have added the image but your question is still not clear to me. Could you put it in simple words and tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, So all I want is to add Columns B2 till E2 and put it in total column F2. And this to continue dynamically in this case till B12 + E12 = F12. Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you just use the SUM formula and drag it down?

Comment: Yes, but this is just for simple sheet not for VBA macros code. I would like it in VBA Code.

Comment: Please add more information to the description about what you are looking for, not in comments.
"its telling me about some reputation stuff and rejecting me to proceed further" - Please expand, do you have an error message?

Comment: @Jon, the problem is not with the above comment. Its with VBA code for: add Columns B2 till E2 and put it in total column F2. And this to continue dynamically in this case till B12 + E12 = F12.

Comment: The problem is that you do not ask a question in your post. If you don't, no one will understand what you are asking for and you will get downvoted and the question will be closed.

Comment: Ok, Sorry I think I got what you are saying. I have now added the question to the code and there is an image too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub hideunwantedcolumns()
    pvtRowCount = pvtTable.TableRange1.Rows.count
    pvtColumnCount = pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns.count
'    Set pvtTotRange = pvtTable.DataBodyRange.Range()
    Set All = oEXLWB.Sheets("PVT_country").Range("A1:R10000")
'    pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns(pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns.Count).Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("PVT_Deal_Value").Range("R1")

    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Country/Area").datarange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2")
    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Geo").datarange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("D2")
    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Corporate").datarange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("F2")

    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Country/Area").LabelRange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B1")
    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Geo").LabelRange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("D1")
    pvtTable.PivotFields("Approval Level").PivotItems("Corporate").LabelRange.Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("F1")
        pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns(pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns.count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("H1")
    pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns(pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("I1")
    pvtTable.TableRange1.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1")

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
     oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B1") = "Others(Count)"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("C1") = "Others(Sum)"
'    oEXLWB.Sheets("Deal_Value").Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Deal_Value").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Deal_Value").Range("C2"), oEXLWB.Sheets("Deal_Value").Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[9]- (RC[2] + RC[4] + RC[6])"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2"), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[7]- (RC[2] + RC[4] + RC[6])"
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("C2"), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2))

    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2"), oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)).Copy
    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Columns(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).Delete    oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Columns(oEXLWB.Sheets("Country").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).Delete
```